# IE not aligning floated crumbs

Tags: html, css

The crumbs on the page [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2013/November/lighting-up-brentwood.html) aren't aligning correctly in IE if someone could take a look, here's the CSS:

```
.crumbs {
margin: 3px 0 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-bottom: 5px solid #323336;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.crumbs li {
float: left;
padding-right: 5px;
color: #999;
}

.crumbs li a {
padding: 0 3px;
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="crumbs clearfix">
   <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a>»</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   </ul>
   <a class="top_submit" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: which IE version you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.crumbs li
remove float left, add display inline and line-height 100%

```
.crumbs li{display:inline; line-height:100%}
```

let me know if this works